# How Do I Solve This Shopware Error The definition for Pugil/Core/System/NumberRange/ValueGenerator/Pattern/ValueGeneratorPatternLanguage has no class

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6, symfony5, symfony5.4

How Do I Solve This Shopware Error The definition for "`Pugil/Core/System/NumberRange/ValueGenerator/Pattern/ValueGeneratorPatternLanguage`" has no class. If you intend to inject this service dynamically at runtime, please mark it as synthetic=true. If this is an abstract definition solely used by child definitions, please add abstract=true, otherwise specify a class to get rid of this error.

I am trying to implement my own solution for generating product number using the Shopware 6 Number Range Feature.

```
<!--this is my xml code-->

<service id="Pugil/Core/System/NumberRange/ValueGenerator/Pattern/ValueGeneratorPatternLanguage">
   <tag name="shopware.value_generator_pattern"/>
</service>
```

**This is my PHP code, I am working with Shopware V6.4.20**

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Pugil\Core\System\NumberRange\ValueGenerator\Pattern;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\Feature;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Log\Package;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\Exception\DecorationPatternException;
use Shopware\Core\System\NumberRange\NumberRangeEntity;

/**
 * @deprecated tag:v6.5.0 - reason:class-hierarchy-change - won't implement ValueGeneratorPatternInterface anymore
 */
#[Package('checkout')]
class ValueGeneratorPatternLanguage extends AbstractValueGenerator implements ValueGeneratorPatternInterface
{
    public const STANDARD_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d';

    public function getPatternId(): string
    {
        return 'lang';
    }

    public function generate(array $config, ?array $args = null, ?bool $preview = false): string
    {
        if ($args === null || \count($args) === 0) {
            $args[] = self::STANDARD_FORMAT;
        }

        return date($args[0]);
    }

    public function getDecorated(): AbstractValueGenerator
    {
        throw new DecorationPatternException(self::class);
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated tag:v6.5.0 will be removed, use `generate()` instead
     */
    public function resolve(NumberRangeEntity $configuration, ?array $args = null, ?bool $preview = false): string
    {
        Feature::triggerDeprecationOrThrow(
            'v6.5.0.0',
            Feature::deprecatedMethodMessage(__CLASS__, __METHOD__, 'v6.5.0.0', 'ValueGeneratorPatternLanguage::generate()')
        );

        $config = [
            'id' => $configuration->getId(),
            'start' => $configuration->getStart(),
            'pattern' => $configuration->getPattern() ?? '',
        ];

        return $this->generate($config, $args, $preview);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shopware is based on the [Symfony framework](https://symfony.com). Particularly it uses the [Symfony DependencyInjection Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html) for, service management and dependency injection. There is a lot to read about services, service container and how Symfony manages them [in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html).

What's relevant in regard to your question is the fact that a service consists of (at least) an id and a class. Usually the id of a service is identical to the FQCN of its class but that is not required.

Now there's multiple ways to define a service. One is just to specify a directory, and Symfony will automatically register all classes in that directory as services. All services will implicitly have their FQCN set as id. Taken directly from the docs:

```xml
<!-- makes classes in src/ available to be used as services -->
<!-- this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name -->
<prototype namespace="App\" resource="../src/" exclude="../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Kernel.php}"/>
```

In your project this seems not be the case, at least your newly created service is not automatically discovered by Symfony. Instead, you have to add it manually. That means you have to specify (at least) the id and class of the service.

So to wrap it up, the service you created has only an id and no class. This is possible in theory (as the error message states: "[i]f this is an abstract definition [...], please add abstract=true"), but in your case you simply want to add the class to your service definition:

```xml
<service
 id="Pugil/Core/System/NumberRange/ValueGenerator/Pattern/ValueGeneratorPatternLanguage"
 class="Pugil/Core/System/NumberRange/ValueGenerator/Pattern/ValueGeneratorPatternLanguage"
>
    <tag name="shopware.value_generator_pattern"/>
</service>
```

Comment: Why is it asking me to add a class. Can you explain the principle/idea behind it to me?

Comment: @IamArobot I expanded my answer a little. I hope that helps.